# How to use Realm Collection Notifications in an ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, realm

I've tried using this sample code from the Realm .NET SDK but my handler code never gets called consistently:

```
var token = realm.All<Person>().SubscribeForNotifications ((sender, changes, error) =>
{
    // Access changes.InsertedIndices, changes.DeletedIndices, and changes.ModifiedIndices
});
```

I've tried running this from a number of different threads, but I suspect none of them have a looper/runloop, a requirement noted in the SDK.  Is it even possible to create a looper/runloop thread in ASP.NET Core that will work with Realm?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out how to implement the looper/run loop that works for Realm Notifications.  The keys parts of the solution are:

1. Use a hosted service to start/stop the thread.
2. Use Nito.AsyncEx to establish a synchronization context for that thread.
3. Loop inside the thread, calling the RefreshAsync method on the realm instance.
4. Call Task.Delay between loop iterations to keep the thread cpu-friendly.

Here is the code:

```
    public class RealmNotificationService : IHostedService
    {
        private System.Threading.Thread _thread;

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(() => Looper(stoppingToken))
                );
            _thread.Start();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async void Looper(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            using (var connection = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync({YOUR-CONFIG}))
            {
                var token = connection.All<{YOUR-OBJECT}>().SubscribeForNotifications((sender, changes, error) =>
                {
                    // Access changes.InsertedIndices, changes.DeletedIndices, and changes.ModifiedIndices
                });
            }
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await connection.Realm.RefreshAsync();
                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bill Raudabaugh's answer almost worked for me. However, the final `while` loop is outside of the `using` so `connection` is undefined.

I was able to get it to work by moving that loop inside of the `using`. Also I removed the `RefreshAsync()` as it seems it's not needed; Realm automatically updates in real time without having to refresh.

Here is my code:

```
public class RealmNotificationService : IHostedService
{
    private System.Threading.Thread _thread;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(() => Looper(stoppingToken))
            );
        _thread.Start();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void Looper(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var connection = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync({YOUR-CONFIG}))
        {
            var token = connection.All<{YOUR-OBJECT}>().SubscribeForNotifications((sender, changes, error) =>
            {
                // Access changes.InsertedIndices, changes.DeletedIndices, and changes.ModifiedIndices
            });
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(2000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```